# Matplotlib Legend Cuts Off Part of Lowest Item Text, Independent of borderpad

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot the results of a scientific computing script, and am running into a weird visual glitch.

My plot is as follows:
[image: PMC_test.png]

As can be seen, the `"$C_-$ Characteristics"` label is somewhat cut off on the bottom.

Because of the way this data is structured, I am plotting each segment individually, specifying color, but not including a label.
The following is how I handle the legend.

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
legend_elements = [
    Line2D([0], [0], color = 'grey', label = "$C_+$ Characteristics"),
    Line2D([0], [0], color = 'red', label = "$C_-$ Characteristics"),
    ]

plt.legend(handles = legend_elements, borderpad = 1.1)
```

It does not seem like changing the value of the `borderpad` parameter changes this last element cutoff. While I can live with this visual glitch, I was wondering if this is a known issue and/or has a solution, as I was unable to find one myself.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on my system. It might depend on the matplotlib version, the backend, on available fonts, ... . You might try to upgrade matplotlib or set a smaller font size.